# IQKeyboardManager: is it possible to change the distance between the UITextField and the Keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, iqkeyboardmanager

[This is the default view without the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gcv2.png)

[This is what happens when the keyboard shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZeGG.png)

I am using the IQKeyboardManagerSwift and would like to reduce the distance between the keyboard and the textfield. I have already tried changing keyboardDistanceFromTextField, but it didn’t change anything, like this:

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 10
```

And yes, the keyboard manager should be working because I already use it’s other functions like the `IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false`

Comment: The distance is because of your own view. Reduce the height of the blue view when keyboard is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by checking if the TextField is active with

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        heightConstraint.constant = 25 
        heightConstraint2.constant = 10
        buttonHeightConstraint.constant = 11
}
```

And if the TextField is active - it changes the constraints that I declared as Outlets. When the TextField isn't active, it changes the constraints  back to the previous values:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        heightConstraint.constant = 60
        heightConstraint2.constant = 20
        buttonHeightConstraint.constant = 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same demo and at my end it showing properly.
Please check
[image]

Only this much code I have done for the keyboard have a look into this.

AppDelegate.swift

```
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldShowToolbarPlaceholder = false
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
```

May be the issue is related to your constraint please check your constraint as well.
If this stuff not help you then please show your constraint applied.